# How to exclude certain characters from like condition in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g

I Have multiple records in table like below. Each record holds mutiple entries separated by @.

```
record1 - 123.45.56:ABCD:789:E @ 1011.1213.1415:FGHI:1617:J @ 
record2 - 123.45.56:ABCD:1617:E @ 1011.1213.1415:FGHI:12345:J @
```

I need to pass an argument to a different project/service which builds an sql query and send the output to me.

Now if I send an argument like below, it gives me wrong output

```
123.45.56:*:1617
```

This recognizes both record1 and record 2 as proper output because of wildcard char. But as per my requirement only record2 is proper as record1 has 123.45.56 in one entry and 1617 in a different entry.

Is there a way to construct an expression that says the like condition to ignore such invalid entries.

Please note that I cant change the query as I am not constructing it. The only way for me is to tweak the expression that I can send as argument.

Comment: Via java code I am passing input to a service. That service uses hibernate to construct the query. This service takes my like condition as it is and constructs  the query. I have see that oracle supports wild cards and pattern matching. I am just checking if we can pass some wildcard/pattern matching chars to achieve this.

Comment: Why don't you choose the characters which makes your selection uniques. Like you can use col LIKE '123.45.56:*12345:J*' ..This will get you only 2nd record.

Answer (score 0):

You need to restrict the pattern you match to be specic enough such that it only matches the first record and not the second one.

You can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE col LIKE '123.45.56:' AND col LIKE '1617:J @'
```